# How can I count ACF sub_field with a certain value

Tags: php, functions, advanced-custom-fields, count

I have a sub field that have several different values. What I'm trying to do is count the number of rows if they're equal to `Mayor`.

So my code looks like this:

```
if( have_rows('candidates') ): 
  while( have_rows('candidates') ): the_row(); 
    $cPosition = get_sub_field('candidate_position');
    if($cPosition == "Mayor"){
      $numrows = count( get_sub_field( 'candidate_position' ) );
    };
  endwhile;
endif;
```

echo $numrows;

However, I'm getting back ALL the rows. So like 17 instead of 8 or so.

Here is the loop giving me my results:

```
<div class="ballot-box ballot-box--mayor">
      <h3 class=""><?php echo _e('Mayor', 'HTML5Blank') ?></h3>

      <p>
        <?php echo _e('The Mayor of San Antonio works closely with City Council to pass laws and create policies for the City, as well as the City Manager, who serves as the City’s chief administrator. While City Council members are elected by district, the Mayor represents all of San Antonio (for a two-year term, with a four-term limit). Candidates are listed here as they will appear on the ballot. All information shared is public information.', 'HTML5Blank') ?>
      </p>
      <p class="text-med"><strong>
        <?php echo _e('Candidates:', 'HTML5Blank') ?> 
        <?php  
          if (have_rows('candidates')):
            $total = 0;
            while (have_rows('candidates')): the_row(); 
              $position = get_sub_field('candidate_position');
              if ($position == "Mayor") {
                $total++;
              };
            endwhile;
            echo $total;
          endif;
        ?>

        </strong></p>
      <p><a class="show-hide" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#mayorCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="mayorCollapse"><i class="fa fa-caret-down text-med" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <span class="toggle-text"><?php echo _e('Show:', 'HTML5Blank') ?> </span> <?php echo _e('Candidates', 'HTML5Blank') ?> </a></p>

      <div class="collapse" id="mayorCollapse">
        <?php 
            if( have_rows('candidates') ): 
        ?>
          <div class="option-box option-box--candidate">
            <?php 
              while( have_rows('candidates') ): the_row(); 
                $cPosition = get_sub_field('candidate_position');
                $cName     = get_sub_field('candidate_name');
                $cImage    = get_sub_field('candidate_photo');
                $cWebsite  = get_sub_field('candidate_website');
                $cPhone    = get_sub_field('candidate_phone');
                $cFB       = get_sub_field('candidate_facebook');
                $cTW       = get_sub_field('candidate_twitter');
                $cIG       = get_sub_field('candidate_instagram');

                if($cPosition == "Mayor"){
            ?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <?php if($cImage){ ?>
                  <img class="responsive" src="<?php echo $cImage ?>" alt="<?php echo $cName; ?>" />
                <?php }else{ ?>
                  <img class="responsive mobile-hide" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/no-photo.png" alt="no photo provided" />
                <?php } ?>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <h4 class=""><?php echo $cName; ?></h4>
                <div class="">
                  <?php if($cWebsite){ ?>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-sa-dark-aqua" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $cWebsite ?>" title="view website" onclick="trackOutboundLink('<?php echo $cWebsite; ?>', true, '<?php echo $cName; ?> Website');">Website</a>
                  <?php } ?>
                 <!--  Fililng document
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-sa-dark-aqua" target="_blank" href="{{ candidate.filing }}" title="view filing document" onclick="trackOutboundLink('{{ candidate.filing }}', true, '<?php echo $cName; ?> Filing');">Filing Document</a>
                -->
                </div>

                <div class="social-icons">
                  <?php if($cFB){ ?>
                    <a class="text-xl nounderline" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $cFB; ?>" title="view facebook page">
                      <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php if($cTW){ ?>
                    <a class="text-xl nounderline" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $cTW; ?>" title="view twitter page">
                      <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php if($cIG){ ?>
                    <a class="text-xl nounderline" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $cIG; ?>" title="view instagram">
                      <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <?php }; //end if ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div><!--./ballot-box -->
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function is generally used to count elements in an array, but you're counting the value of a string, and that always returns 1. You can just add 1 in your if statement.

Something like this:

```php
if (have_rows('candidates')):
  $total = 0;
  while (have_rows('candidates')): the_row(); 
    $position = get_sub_field('candidate_position');
    if ($position == "Mayor") {
      $total++;
    };
  endwhile;
  echo $total;
endif;
```

Other than that, the code actually looks right. Where are you initializing `$numrows` and where are you checking the value? Do you get a different value using the code above?

Comment: I still get 1 with your code. But your code does make sense. Not sure why it's not counting correctly. I was using the code from here: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/count-total-number-of-repeater-rows/

Comment: The first thing I would check is that you're actually getting the correct value when you're calling `get_sub_field('candidate_position')`. Print out each iteration of `candidate_position` and check if it contains around eight `Mayor` instances. Because note that you're iterating over `candidates`, but then calling an entirely different field for counting. Those numbers may not be the same.

Comment: It does. Right below that I have a `while` loop. The loop is returning everything correctly. I posted the loop code above

Comment: When you said you get 1 with my code, are you saying you're getting a total of just 1?

Comment: Yes. It's returning the number 1.

Comment: That would seem to indicate that `have_rows('candidates')` only has one thing to iterate over, and the first item `get_sub_field('candidate_position')` happens to be `Mayor,` or that it iterates over many things, but there is only one `Mayor` present. Without seeing the other code and the data stored, it's difficult to troubleshoot further. The code, as you have it written, is correct. (Provided you did use my code and initialized `$total`, otherwise it just stores the last occurrence, which would always be 1.)

Comment: I just added the entire loop. And this loop is absolutely returning the correct things. I just need to count them. Let me know if that helps or changes anything.

Comment: This is more helpful, but I don't see where you're counting there?

Comment: Oh, I apologize. There's no counting going on there. I need to count to show how many candidates there are. I was just saying that the loop I have is returning the correct results.

Comment: Show us how you count in that code. In fact, replace your first code block with the extended code block, including the code that's not working. Also, before you were counting how many mayors there are, which is different from how many candidates there are.

Comment: I just updated the code with the count that isn't working. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but the original answer by NightHawk is working now. Not sure if I was cached or what. Thanks!!!